# I want to export the date row with the same date from another excel

Tags: python, datetime, if-statement

I am new to Python, and I am about to solve some simple questions.

I have two excel datasets. The first one contains the samples I have taken on different days, with a separate "dates" column and a "month" column, as below:

[image]

and the other excel, with the date I only wanted

[image]

and I want to filter the first excel with the dates that are equal to the second excel, and print out the rows that meet these conditions.

Here is my code:
1st attempt:

````
import datetime

import pandas
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl
from pandas import DataFrame
from datetime import datetime
import datetime as dt
import numpy as np

df_1=pd.read_excel('waterstationin29UMT.xlsx',sheet_name='Sheet1') #first excel
print(df_1)
df_2=pd.read_excel('29UMTdate.xlsx',sheet_name='Sheet1') #second excel
print(df_2)

minyan_d = df_2.iloc[1:11:,1:4]              #only want the date information
print(type(minyan_d))
# obtain datetime series:
df_2_1=pd.to_datetime(minyan_d['system:time_start'],format='%Y/%m/%d') 
print(type(df_2_1.dt.year))
water_date = df_1['SampDay']
water_month = df_1['SampMonth']
df_1.where((df_1['SampDay'] == df_2_1.dt.day) and (df_1['SampMonth'] == df_2_1.dt.month))
```
````

and get the bug said that 'Can only compare identically-labeled series objects'

````
second attempt:
```for x in water_date:
   for y in water_month:
      if [x == (df_2_1.dt.day)] and [y ==(df_2_1.dt.month)]:
         print(1)
      else:
         print(2)
````

I know some of the data in the first excel can not be found in the second excel, but I do not know why I only get one. I am new to Python. Just forgive the naive problems I have made.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`merge()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html).

Example:

```
merged = pd.merge(df_1, df_2, how='inner', on=['SampMonth'])
```

This will join the rows that have the same entry in the `SampMonth` column across the dataframes. You can also use `how="outer"`, which results in a different merge.

Read the documentation to learn how to use it for your needs - it is quite helpful.

Or, if you just want to filter one dataframe, you could do this:

```
df_1 = df_1[df_1["SampMonth" == <insert month here>]]
```

This will return the rows in the dataframe where the month matches what you want -- you can make the internal boolean a compound boolean, as in `(condition 1) & (condition 2) & (condition 3)` to make the whole date match.

Comment: Hello, thanks a lot for your help. The 'merge' function can not be used I think,because the date is in different format. since the two datasets, the first one is date is one column, and month is in another column, as depict in the 1st images I inserted in the very beginning.  And in the second datasets, the date just like 23/4/2022.    and the second advice: I edited my code just like ```df_1 = df_1[df_1["SampMonth" == df_2_1.dt.month] & df_1['SampDay'== df_2_1.dt.day]]```

Comment: and get the bug: 'Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match)' do you know how can I fix it?

Comment: to use a compound boolean, it must be inside of the brackets, with parentheses around each condition.

Comment: sorry, I have edited my code several times. and it still gets bug. Could you tell me the right format for this?

Answer (score 0):

guys. I think I found the solution, but still being very complicated, I have transferred the first excel's data to day/month/year format, and compare these two via this code:)
minmin = df_1['value'].isin(df_2.iloc[0:11,5:8]) which give me False/True.
Any efficient and time-saving codes are needed also!